# TailwindCSS styles not applied on Nextjs server side

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I'm following the tutorial on how to integrate TailwindCSS and NextJS here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

It all works fine. I can get the job done and see some styles being applied in my home page. However, those styles are applied only on the client-side. I've checked the Network tab and I only saw the word "Home" without any background instead of the gray one I have setup.

Here is how it looks on the browser:

[image]

And here is how it looks on the Chrome preview from what was generated on the server:

[image]

Here's my code:

Tailwind.config.js
[image]

postcss.config.js
[image]

_app.js

[image]

What can I be making wrong? Anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as snippets, do not use images for code.

Comment: HI juliomalves! I can do that, but these are very simple autogenerated snippets. They are described in the tailwindcss docs and mostly autogenerated (except the _app.js, which I had to add the import)